# Why do I get the error "429_client_error" with my Slack bot?

Tags: node.js, slack-api

I am working on a note taking Slack bot and I keep getting the `429_client_error`. First of all, is it the same error as the `429 too many requests error` describe in the Slack API documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/rate-limits) ? If not, what is it ?

If it is indeed due to the Slack rate limits, I don't understand. I printed a log of all the bot answers and they are sent at least a second apart. I also have the error even when I use the note taking bot "very slowly" and wait between requests.

Here is an exemple of interaction.

> User : I want to add a note.
>
> Slack-Bot : Sure. What is the content of your note ?
>
> User : I met with my Abigail yesterday. I need to send him the
>   pictures I took Saturday.
>
> Slack-Bot : Go on.
>
> User : I am done.
>
> Slack-Bot : Great. You can add one of the following participants to
>   your note.
>
> > 1. Abigail Allan
> > 2. Brian Bernard
> > 3. Carl Carlson
> > 4. Done

At this last part, I use interactive messages with buttons to propose participants. Behind the scenes, I actually load more than 3 people, so when the user chooses to add Brian for example, my bot replaces the whole message with a new list of participants the user can choose from. Then, when the user is done, he has to select the last button "done".

In other words, I have a list of buttons that keeps updating each time the user select one item in the list until the user is satisfied.

This seems to be part of the problem, since I seem to get the `429_client_error` only at this stage of the conversation. I use delays to ensure that the Slack bot does not answer too fast for the user. I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this problem ?

Comment: I have some issue when more than 100 channels requests WebClient for files.list data gives Rate limiting error then stop getting files data

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem @EmiliePicard-Cantin?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on a python application for slack and found a discussion about it in the [slacker github repo](https://github.com/os/slacker).

According to the slacker main developer `os`, the solution are local caches of the information. They're even providing a sample code [here](https://github.com/os/slacker/issues/133):

```py
from slacker import Users

class CachedUsers(Users):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Users, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user_ids = {}

    def get_user_id(self, user_name):
        user_id = self.user_ids.get(user_name)

        if not user_id:
            user_id = super().get_user_id(user_name)
            self.user_ids[user_name] = user_id

        return user_id
```

If you're looking into stuff that cannot be cached locally before, check out the [rate limits](https://api.slack.com/docs/rate-limits) you can find the tier on each method in the Slack API.